# Why do cards miss their timing?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My specific question is regarding **Lightpulsar Dragon** and why it misses it's timing (*such as when synchro summoning*), while cards like **Tuningware** don't. I am mainly just looking for an explanation as to how and why cards miss timing, as I have been playing Yugioh for years, but have never quite understood why timing is such a frustrating rule to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Pulsar says **when**, tuningware says **if**.

When Pulsar is sent to the grave during synchro summoning is in the middle of a resolving chain, and nothing can occur other than the resolving chain.

However tuningware and similar cards that say if only require it to go to the grave sometime during a chain to have their effect go off